# Repaint page without window focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

When I update my css files my server sends a message to the client to do something like this...

```
tag.href = h + ((if h.indexOf("?") >= 0 then "&" else "?")) + (new Date().valueOf())
```

It tells the client to pull down another version of the css file, which will be the new one.

This works great if the chrome window has focus but when I'm in my text editor the changes will not be painted until I resume focus on the chrome window.

This is a somewhat recent change as it used to work fine in chrome and still works fine in firefox.

Is there anyway to force chrome to repaint the page even when it doesn't have focus?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @MarceloBezerra I don't see how this helps.

Comment: you can put the logic tha checks if the page needs to be repainted in a function, and then, you call this function periodically (even if its not focused) with the help of setTimeInterval ;-)

Comment: @MarceloBezerra the problems isn't triggering the logic, the client gets a message via websocket to trigger the logic. The logic fires too, things like console.log work just fine. The style changes just won't happen until chrome app regains focus. (the point is the see the changes in real-time) Like i said this also works as-is in firefox so it related to how chrome repaints.